# Show Dataverse but restrict tables

Tags: security, powerapps, dataverse

I’m trying to work out what permissions for the relevant security role I need.

I’ve got it so that the user can only see tables that I’ve given them access to in PowerApps, but they also need to see it in Dataverse. They don’t have permission to view Dataverse so I’m wondering what is the minimum set of permissions for a security role to view Dataverse?

Answer (score 0):

They need to be a licensed user on Dataverse and have a basic security role assigned.

Comment: They are a `Basic user` so can see Dataverse, but they can also see system tables in Dataverse that I haven’t given them access to. How do I hide specifically the User table from them?